# Iterando un objeto JSON con javascript

Tags: javascript, bucles, javascript-objeto

Tengo una duda.
Estoy trabajando un menú de un restaurante, y los platillos, precios y descripciones, las he almacenado en un objeto JSON. Mi problema es que dentro del objeto, tengo dos array con más objetos, para separar según sea la categoría. Por ejemplo tengo la categoría productos y otros productos.

Ejemplo

````
```
let productList = {
        
productos:[
  {
   'producto': 'Molks Sencilla',
   'precio': '$40.00',
    'desc': 'Hamburguesa sencilla con queso amarillo'
  }
    
],
otrosProductos: [
{
 'producto': 'Hot Dog',
 'precio': '$40.00',
 'desc': 'Hecho con salchicha de pavo envuelta en tocino'
}]
};
````

```
Para acceder al primer array utilizo un ciclo for desde una función:
```

```
function cardProducts(){
    for(let i = 0; i <= productList.productos.length; i++){
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = `<span>${productList.productos[i].producto}</span> 
        ${productList.productos[i].precio}<br/><p class='pDesc'>${productList.productos[i].desc}`;
        menuList.appendChild(li);
    }
}cardProducts();
```

```
Hasta ahí todo va bien, pues me imprime en el navegador todos los objetos del primer array, pero en consola me aparece el siguiente error aunque el resultado lo imprima bien en la web. 

**main.js:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'producto' of undefined
    at cardProducts (main.js:82)
    at main.js:85**

**Y mi problema es que no puedo acceder al segundo array de los otros productos, trate por medio de otro ciclo for pero no dio resultado, ya que esos productos van pintarse en otro div**
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer algo como esto, lo que hace es primero iterar sobre el objeto padre, despues itera sobre cada objeto dentro del padre y obtiene los valores, recuerda que por la sintaxis que estas usando tienes un `JSON Array` y su tratamiento es un poco diferente al de un `JSON` normal o al de un `Array` normal

```js
let productList = {
        
  productos:[
    {
     'producto': 'Molks Sencilla',
     'precio': '$40.00',
      'desc': 'Hamburguesa sencilla con queso amarillo'
    }

  ],
  otrosProductos: [
  {
   'producto': 'Hot Dog',
   'precio': '$40.00',
   'desc': 'Hecho con salchicha de pavo envuelta en tocino'
  }]
};

for(i in productList){
  productList[i].forEach(e=>console.info(e["producto"]));
}
```